# how to get imagelink(url) from listview onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

how to get ImageLink(url) from listview OnitemClickListener my app contain image from server in list i want when user click to row i want to next page an show image in this activity and also share to social media i spand the 3 day in this topic my code is below.....

**my Code is**

```
private static final int REQ_SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
byte dataArray[] = new byte[1024];
ProgressDialog progressdialog;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
public static final int Progress_Dialog_Progress = 0;
private List<String> videoURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
ShareDialog shareDialog;
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayList<String> spinnerdata;
private JSONArray result;
private boolean isImage = false;


// list view data
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
String url = "http://www.example.com/image.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Model> movieList = new ArrayList<Model>();
private ListView listView;
private Image_Adapter adapter;
final Json_Data j_data = new Json_Data();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_activity);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    spinnerdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.txtSpinner);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    listdata();
    spinnerdata.add("Get Category");
    adapter = new Image_Adapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
           final TextView tv_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgtext);

        }
    });
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

/****************************Getting ListView Data From Json************************************/

public void listdata()
{
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
                {
                    hidePDialog();
                    Log.e(TAG, response.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Model model = new Model();
                            String image_json= obj.getString("image");
                            String img_txt = obj.getString("txt");
                            Log.e(TAG,"Image"+image_json);
                            Log.e(TAG,"Image Text"+img_txt);
                            model.setThumbnailUrl(image_json);
                            model.setImg_text(img_txt);
                            movieList.add(model);
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
 public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}
private void hidePDialog()
{
    if (pDialog != null)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: try getting the image link by passing the `position` to the model

Comment: `movieList.get(position).getThumbnailUrl();` try this.. Before create a function in model returing thumbnail url

Comment: i try it also but not worked

Comment: Can you post your full code for the Activity/Fragment ?

Comment: Use `Activity.this` in this line `Image_Adapter(this, movieList);`

Comment: And one more thing,.. Are you getting the correct position in the `itemClickListener` ?

Comment: yes i am getting correct position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114627/discussion-between-sanoop-and-newdev).

Comment: Upvote if it worked.. Thanks :) :) Happie coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Add the returning Function on Model

```
    public String getImageUrl(){ 
      return imageUrl;
    }
```

The in the `OnItemClickListener` get the image Url

```
    String _URL = movieList.get(position).getImageUrl();
```